# Solving for the height of liquid in an eccentric annulus in an horizontal concentric cylinders

Tags: systems-of-equations

I have a case where I have an inner tube within an outer tube.  The tubes can be anything from concentric to fully eccentric with the inner tube laying on the bottom of the outer tube.  I want to calculate the height of fluid in the annulus knowing the volume. I know can calculate the area (and volume by extension) for each part using the following equations for the fully eccentric case:

$$A_o = cos^{-1}((r_o-h)/r_0)\cdot r_o^2 - (r_o-h)\sqrt{2r_oh-h^2}$$
$$A_i = cos^{-1}((r_i-h)/r_i)\cdot r_i^2 - (r_i-h)\sqrt{2r_ih-h^2}$$
$$V = (A_o-A_i)\cdot L$$

Where:
$r_o$ is the radius larger cylinder internal diameter
$r_i$ is the radius if the inner cylinder
$h$ is the height of the fluid
$A_o$ is the area outer
$A_i$ is the area inner
$L$ is the length of the cylinder
$V$ is the volume of fluid in the annulus

What I would like to do is solve the equation for h so I can directly calculate it.

Currently, I am solving each equation separately in excel and taking the difference.  I build a table for incremental heights and then use the table to lookup the height for a given volume.  It works but it seems like solving the equations would quicker.  The math is beyond me though.  Any ideas would be helpful.

Thanks!

Hogwildwa

Comment: MathJax is the formatting method used in Math Stack Exchange! Since you're a new user, I've done my best to format it for you (and an admin will soon review my edit), but in the future, type out your answers with this guide in mind: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference